# AppleRAID 0+1 failure: [corestorage] LVG missing and cannot repair mirror

Tags: disk-utility

I just recently created a corestorage LVG and an encrypted volume that used an AppleRAID 0+1 array, but something has gone horribly wrong.

I had four 1TB disks, and created two 2TB stripes, `cbs1` and `cbs2`, and mirrored them in Disk Utility. Then I created a [corestorage] LVG and fed it the UUID of the mirrored device, and created an encrypted jHFS+ filesystem at 100% of the capacity of the 2TB mirror.

This worked great, and behaved nicely for over a week. Today I had a software update that resulted in a reboot, and my RAID didn't show up. The LVG I created using the AppleRAID is no longer showing up in `diskutil cs list` and the mirror was set to auto repair and was making progress (it looked like cbs1 vanished but it was still there, so I thought it was an intermittent hardware issue on boot) and I let it make progress on the rebuild until it was complete, but it didn't end up the way I thought it would.

I now saw in `diskutil ar list` that I had a missing or damaged mirror device, and so in an effort to be smart, I created another stripe of two other 1TB disks, called it `cbs3` and attempted to add that as a spare or a member to the UUID of the mirror. *HOWEVER*, this fails with an error of `-69848: Couldn't modify RAID set` in both cases.

`diskutil ar list` now gives me the following:

```
AppleRAID sets (4 found)
===============================================================================
Name:                 cbs1
Unique ID:            1E127495-1FDE-4521-A941-5E5DC31245DD
Type:                 Stripe
Status:               Online
Size:                 2.0 TB (1999721791488 Bytes)
Rebuild:              manual
Device Node:          -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  disk6s2   AA501823-4955-473B-A27E-0EEA9E75072A  Online     999860895744
1  disk7s2   A6486548-3E07-4C0F-8F88-BE909D23DC22  Online     999860895744
===============================================================================
===============================================================================
Name:                 Untitled
Unique ID:            1E127495-1FDE-4521-A941-5E5DC31245DD
Type:                 Mirror
Status:               Online
Size:                 2.0 TB (1999721758720 Bytes)
Rebuild:              automatic
Device Node:          -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-  -none-    1E127495-1FDE-4521-A941-5E5DC31245DD  Missing/Damaged
1  -none-    2B52C67D-801E-4481-A76B-F98FF28C13B5  Online     1999721758720
===============================================================================
===============================================================================
Name:                 cbs2
Unique ID:            2B52C67D-801E-4481-A76B-F98FF28C13B5
Type:                 Stripe
Status:               Online
Size:                 2.0 TB (1999721791488 Bytes)
Rebuild:              manual
Device Node:          -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  disk8s2   890A3BB9-94CB-4E02-8580-5F16D94890FF  Online     999860895744
1  disk10s2  71C4DE7E-6EC2-4660-9CDA-0ED31574925D  Online     999860895744
===============================================================================
===============================================================================
Name:                 cbs3
Unique ID:            A153709E-88C8-4281-8268-F68C26077E6A
Type:                 Stripe
Status:               Online
Size:                 2.0 TB (1999721791488 Bytes)
Rebuild:              manual
Device Node:          disk14
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  disk2s2   C1227A8B-8215-4E7E-99C8-C8491B7D994F  Online     999860895744
1  disk4s2   A65356C3-270C-404B-82AC-9EAB042B9300  Online     999860895744
===============================================================================
```

This is doubly confusing because there is no `DevNode` for the mirror'ed volume, probably due to it previously being fed to `corestorage`. The mirror device doesn't show up in Disk Utility.app, but I see it as above in the CLI.

Flailing a little, I tried to repair the mirror using both UUIDs to no avail:

```
lindsay:~$ sudo diskutil ar repairmirror 1E127495-1FDE-4521-A941-5E5DC31245DD /dev/disk14
Password:
Started RAID operation
Can't add spare to the RAID set
Error: -69848: Couldn't modify RAID
lindsay:~$ sudo diskutil ar repairmirror 2B52C67D-801E-4481-A76B-F98FF28C13B5 /dev/disk14
Started RAID operation
Can't add spare to the RAID set
Error: -69848: Couldn't modify RAID
```

Uh oh!

Is it possible to import the corestorage LVG that I created against the mirror'ed device while the mirror is degraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two sets use the same UUID!

```
Stripe-1
Name:                 cbs1
Unique ID:            1E127495-1FDE-4521-A941-5E5DC31245DD

Stripe-2
Name:                 cbs2
Unique ID:            2B52C67D-801E-4481-A76B-F98FF28C13B5

Create a mirror
Name:                 Untitled
Unique ID:            1E127495-1FDE-4521-A941-5E5DC31245DD
```

That mirror has the same UUID as Stripe-1. You have defined a loop.

Maybe that's the source of your problem. You need a disktool to directly modify the contents of your disks to create unique UUIDs.